# flex: Ability to drag+drop a movieclip

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop, movieclip, swc

In order to improve user experience we want the ability to have an animated movieclip of a turning wheel- and have the ability to drag and drop it anywhere on a defined area

We have built the rotating wheel as a swc file.

How do we do the drag+drop. Examples that I have seen, cater to only dropping of images. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the Flex classes for drag and drop you'll need to wrap that movieClip in an a [UIComponent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html); which has all the events related to drag and drop.

Here are some [good instructions](http://www.flexafterdark.com/docs/Flex-DragAndDrop).  To copy the relevant pieces:

> Make a Component Draggable
>
> 1. Add listener for MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN
> 2. Determine drag initiator and hand-off to DragManager
>
> To kick off a drag-n-drop, you'll need
>   a MouseEvent for the component to be
>   dragged.

```
public function makeDraggable( component:IUIComponent ):void
{
   // a mouseDown event will start the drag
   component.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, beginDrag );
}

public function beginDrag( mouseEvent:MouseEvent ):void
{
   // the drag initiator is the object being dragged (target of the mouse event)
   var dragInitiator:IUIComponent = mouseEvent.currentTarget as IUIComponent;

   // the drag source contains data about what's being dragged
   var dragSource:DragSource = new DragSource();

   // ask the DragManger to begin the drag
   DragManager.doDrag( dragInitiator, dragSource, mouseEvent, null );
}
```

Comment: Thanks- I am now doing it for an image- Understand, I simply need to create a UI container and place my swc in that- and the same drag-drop logic for image will apply for that UI container.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the `dragProxy` for the `movieClip` to hold an instance of it instead of a fixed image.